# PHP both if and else being accessed

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have some code, below, that checks to see if a session exists, then prints off the correct HTML accordingly.

```
<?php

// check if session started
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_NONE):?>

    JUNK HERE!!!

<?php
else:?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- START START START START START START START -->

        <head>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>2300 Edit</title>
            <meta name="author" content="Kenny Hall">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

            <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="access.js"></script>

        </head>


        <body>

            <div>
                <label for="ac">Access Code:</label>
                <input id="ac" name="ac" type="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Go!">
            </div>

        </body>

    <!-- END END END END END END END -->
    </html>

<?php endif;

?>
```

I've tried switching the content in the `if/else` statements, and the same stuff gets printed off. What might I be doing wrong?

Also, is this an acceptable practice, of how I'm printing `html` this way? I really do not want to include other files because it would be insecure simply due to someone just navigating to the directory where the include is located and running it independently, outside of my session control.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What do you mean, "the same stuff gets printed off"? Do both sections get displayed, or does the same one display regardless of the if conditional value? If so, which, the if or the else?

Comment: @Kenny if you include other files no one will know where they come from unless they can see the code in your program, though typically on smaller projects session control is used as an include in every other page...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it always prints the `else` statement. It can't seem to figure out that there's a session. In code elsewhere that I know is being executed, I use `session_start();` to start a session.

Comment: including other files is NOT insecure if you do it correctly. Most of your includes should just be sets of functions that return values. You're basically mixing your view and your template which while not technically good practice should be ok on small projects. Better would be to learn and incorporate some light frameworks and/or well known design patterns (MVC, MVVM) for both future maintainability, and the ability to grow your team (it will be easier to bring them up to speed) and codebase!

Answer (score 0):

here's a better session check snippet from the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)

```
<?php
/**
* @return bool
*/
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Example
if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
?>
```